# Customize phone call (using sim) UI on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call, viber

Normally if we want to make a phone call from our application, we need open NSURL from app with prefix: tel://

However, I want to customize phone call UI that using sim card on phone from app. Do u have any idea about that.
If you know Viber app, you can see that app already done it.
You can choose to call by using Viber api or using sim card. When you use sim card call, you can see customized phone call UI.

Comment: Do you want to make UI for dial pad instead of just alert of calling?

Comment: No, I want to customize UI while calling not before calling.